# Oracle IOT gives count(1) as 0 even thought it has entries in them

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle11gr2

We have an IOT in oracle 11g R2, The table has entries in it. But when we select the count(1) from  that table, it returns 0. We droped and re-created the table and it worked fine for some time, however the issue resurfaced after some DML operations.

Seems to be some kind of index corruption. We would appreciate inputs on finding the root cause.

Comment: I've removed the *iot* tag as it's for Internet of Things and not index-organized tables.

Comment: That sounds like a bug that you should be talking to Oracle Support about.

Comment: Do you have a secondary index on the IOT, and is that being used in the plan for the count query? [Possibly bug 14472647 if so?](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=14472647.8)

Comment: Was the `select` run in the same session that inserted the rows? If not, was the `insert` committed?